# sorting dynamically pulled files

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I am trying to dynamically load files from a directory and then sort them in order by their month.  Starting in July and then going to June.

Here is what I have so far --

```
function monthCompare($a, $b) {
    $a = strtolower($a);
    $b = strtolower($b);
    $months = array(
        'July' => 1,
        'August' => 2,
        'September' => 3,
        'October' => 4,
        'November' => 5,
        'December' => 6,
        'January' => 7,
        'February' => 8,
        'March' => 9,
        'April' => 10,
        'May' => 11,
        'June' =>12,

    );

    if($a == $b)
        return 0;

    if(!isset($months[$a]) || !isset($months[$b]))
        return $a > $b;

    return ($months[$a] > $months[$b]) ? 1 : -1;

}

usort($filearray, "monthCompare");
```

Here is the code I think isn't working.

Thanks

1. These files are minutes and their name format are as "month-day-year"
2. These files can be modified at any time by anybody
3. He believes there are problems with the way he is using the function usort

Comment: It doesn't work.  it just sorts them alphabetically

Comment: How about narrowing down the problem just a little bit for us?

Comment: These are minutes from a committee that need to be sorted by month starting in July and ending in June.  Right now it is sorting them alphabetically by the months.  And I am trying to get it to order it in the way I want.

Comment: So I am trying to use the usort with a function like I saw on an earlier problem but it isn't working for me

Comment: I think you should re-structure your code first. Divide it into multiple functions so it's easier for you to retain the overview.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function [filectime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php). On unix this function will return you back the date of the file's last modification time (carefull though because on windows this will give you back the file creation time). You can use this function to sort the files based on when their modified which will work for your note taking texts.

Comment: I don't know if this is fireproof.  What if some edits it done in a year or whatever. I think that I need to do it base on file names.

Comment: Well you need to be more specific then. Do people come back and edit minutes? How are your file names stored? Which piece of your code do you think is not working? These are all questions you should answer while stating the initial question.

Comment: They might be coming back to edit minutes I want to make sure they can and not mess up the sorting. My files are stored like this -- august-16-2010.pdf.

I think it is the function monthCompare and then also the usort command that are not working

Comment: Why don't you just take the name and break it into three different fields. Month, day, and year. Compare each file against all other files and give it a ranking. First compare the year, then the month then the day. Sorry if I'm not reading your code and giving you all these other suggestions but this is what this site is about; giving help not debugging somebody's whole code.

Answer (score 0):

How about turning the filename into into [unix timestamps](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and sort by that? Like this:

```php
$files = array('january-25-2012.pdf', 'february-2-2012.pdf');
$sorted_array = array();

foreach($files as $key => $file) {
   $name = explode(".", $file);
   $nix_date = strtotime($name[0]); // turn to unix timestamp
   $sorted_array[$nix_date] = $name[0];
}
// sort by keys
ksort($sorted_array);
```

Will result in:

```
 array(2) {
   [1327522320] => string(15) "january-25-2012"
   [1328213520] => string(15) "february-2-2012"
 }
```